# Any alternative to 'PaymentMethodOperation' for v15

Tags: python, google-ads-api

So i am currently developing for googleads api v15,
Issue is

```
@app.route('/add_payment_method', methods=['POST'])
def add_payment_method_api():
    # Get the JSON data from the request
    data = request.get_json()
    
    # Extract the necessary information from the JSON data
    refresh_token = data.get('refresh_token')
    customer_id = data.get('customer_id')
    config_dict = {
        'login_customer_id': config.get('Google Manager', 'google_manager_id'),
        'developer_token': developer_token,
        'client_id': client_id,
        'client_secret': client_secret,
        'refresh_token': refresh_token,
        'use_proto_plus': False,
    }

    # Build the Google Ads client
    client = GoogleAdsClient.load_from_dict(config_dict, version="v15")
    # Add the payment method to the customer's account using the Google Ads API
    try:
        # Authenticate with Google Ads API using the refresh token

        # Create the payment method operation
        payment_method_operation = client.get_type('PaymentMethodOperation')
        payment_method = payment_method_operation.create
        payment_method.customer = client.get_service('CustomerService').customer_path(
            customer_id
        )
        payment_method.payment_method_type = client.enums.PaymentMethodTypeEnum.CREDIT_CARD
        payment_method.credit_card.number = data.get('credit_card_number')
        payment_method.credit_card.expiration_month = data.get('expiration_month')
        payment_method.credit_card.expiration_year = data.get('expiration_year')
        payment_method.credit_card.cvv = data.get('cvv')
        
        # Add the payment method to the customer's account
        response = client.service.payment_method.mutate_payment_methods(
            customer_id=customer_id, operations=[payment_method_operation]
        )
        
        # Return the response as JSON
        return jsonify(response)
    
    except GoogleAdsException as ex:
        # Handle any exceptions from the Google Ads API
        return jsonify({str(ex)})
    
    except Exception as ex:
        # Handle any other exceptions
        return jsonify({str(ex)})
```

If you look at the code at payment_method_operation = client.get_type('PaymentMethodOperation')
it constantly says that payment method operation is not avalaible for v15, Why? is there any alternative, well ive searched and have not found anything that matches up to that. if not how do i add a credit card or paypal account programatically?

I have tried using v14 etc but it messes with the rest of my code. i have also tried adding paypal instead but unfortunately it didnt work

Comment: Could you share the documentation where you initially found `PaymentMethodOperation`? It's possible to set up new [Payments accounts](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/billing/billing-setups) over the Ads API, but I don't think you can add credit card details.